# why is this syntax exclusively used to initialize string literals and can't be used for an array of characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, constructor, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [initializing char arrays in a way similar to initializing string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216462/initializing-char-arrays-in-a-way-similar-to-initializing-string-literals)

below is a sample of initializing a string literal in which a terminating null character is added at the end of string, necessarily:

```
char reshte[]="sample string";
```

I wonder why can't we initialize an array of characters without terminating null character, in that way and we have to use the following syntax instead, that is exhausting in case there is a large number of characters:

```
char reshte[]={'s','a','m','p','l','e',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'};
```

Comment: When there is a large number of characters, one additional null character at the end doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: I think it really does matter in my case that I don't need that at all.

Comment: Closed as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216462/initializing-char-arrays-in-a-way-similar-to-initializing-string-literals/3216585#3216585 asked by the same questioner. The other one asks for a macro to work around it in addition and was given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the string without the terminating character so badly. Storage/performance wise, it doesn't make it an issue. You can just work knowing there's a null character at the end you don't need for your application, if you want to use that instantiation.

Or you could maybe do something like:

```
char reshte[]="sample strin";
reshte[strlen(reshte)]='g';
```

Comment: so you mean, not using that terminating null character is not a poor software design ?

Comment: It's probably a terrible software design decision. But it can be made in specific scenarios. Something to consider: If there's someone who's going to maintain your code, they have to be able to follow it easily. "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: yeah you're right, I wouldn't want to argue with someone like that!!!

Comment: violent psychopath... excellent, I've got to remember that one. +1.

Answer (score 4):

That is because in C characters inside "" are considered a string and a string is terminated by zero.

```
char reshte[]={ '1', '2', '3', '4' };
```

is also efficient and does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why can't we initialize an array of characters **without terminating null character**

Which language are we talking about? If you manually supply the length, you can do it in C:

```
char reshte[13]="sample string";
```

This is an error in C++ though.