# Initializer-string for char array is too long

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

I have read 
[char four[4] = "four"; What are the correct semantics for this statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524053/char-four4-four-what-are-the-correct-semantics-for-this-statement)

I am using `Xcode` and writing `Objective C` code.
I don't understand why:

```
char words[4] = { "aardvark", "abacus", "allude", "zygote" };
```

gives a warning

> warning: Semantic Issue: Initializer-string for char array is too long

but

```
char *words[4] = { "aardvark", "abacus", "allude", "zygote" };
```

works fine.
Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of the differences between an integer pointer and a character pointer. Hence, I was confused. This helped me:
http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/why-this-works-char-pointer-in-c/4444.html