# How can this char array store four separate strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm confused by this snippet from the book I'm reading. Text strings are put into a `char` array. There are four words, with four elements in the array. Wait, but that means a single `char` element is containing a whole text string. I'm certain `chars` can only handle a single character. Here's the code.

```
const char *words[4] = { "aardvark", "abacus", 
    "allude", "zygote" };
```

So what gives? How can the author be using `chars` to store whole strings? I know the solution must be blindingly obvious, but I just can't see it. Also, what's with the `const` keyword? Why would it need to be read only if all we plan to do with this array is count the length of each word using `strlen()`?

Comment: Very similar (apparently this person is reading the same book): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876693/initializer-string-for-char-array-is-too-long

Comment: You're right. Evidence perhaps that this particular book, doesn't thoroughly explain what it's doing. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code does not use chars to store strings, note that the declaration is an *array of* `char *`.

A `char` can hold a single character, and a `char *` can be used to point to the first element of an array of characters, which can hold a standard C string. This is an important C fundamental: see a `char *` and you should immediately think of null-terminated C strings.

Similarly, an `int *` can be used to refer to an entire array of `int`, by holding the address of the *first* `int` in the array. `int*` can be subscripted the same as an array declared using `[]`.

A `char *` can also be used to simply hold the address of a single character - i.e. not the first character in a null terminated string.

Comment: I think the asker knows that - what he missed is that the `const char* words[]` syntax resolves to `const char** words`

Comment: Right, that explains a lot. The `char *` must have alluded me. I'll have to go research that now, but surely using a `char *` limits you greatly with regards to going through each character in that string. Normally you would use `word [5]` to get the 5th letter in the word, but this isn't possible using `char *` is it? Thanks again for the helpful answer, I've marked you up and will make this the accepted answer when possible.

Comment: @Mackey18 the same is possible: you _can_ index e.g. `char *` the same as `char[]`, and of course the same for other types

Comment: @Mackey18 the array syntax you mentioned is actually a shortcut for pointer arithmetic - it actually resolves to `(word + 5)` - and resolves the same whether you're using `char*` or char `word[]` - that's why strings in c are null terminated - otherwise you wouldn't know where the end is

Comment: Yup `words[1][3]` should evaluate to the `'c'` in `"abacus"`.

Comment: Ok so in this example, I could use `(word [2] + 5)` to get the 5th char of the second char array, i.e. U? Is this correct. EDIT: Just saw your comment Analog, that seems like a much nicer way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: @Mackey18 read through this - it's good stuff http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: That's a good read, very detailed and covers lots. I still find it strange that having read a whole book on C that covered strings and arrays in depth, it was never mentioned that `char*` would create an array of chars. The only strings it covered were purely in the form of `char word [i]` where i are the individual characters.

Comment: Sorry, I know I shouldn't ask follow up questions, but here goes. A large portion of my C learning was to do with the fact that defined arrays waste memory if it's not used, i.e. an array of `comment [250]` (giving you 250 characters to write a comment) would be wasteful if the input only used 100 characters. Does a `char *` completely circumnavigate this issue, making it very memory efficient? Furthermore, am I right in saying that it automatically adds a Null at the end, so I know longer have to manually add a null to a string from an input buffer?

Comment: using `char *` doesn't really change how many unused elements you might end up with in an array. you'll typically still need to decide on an upper-bound for your buffer, and typicall won't fill it all. This really isn't a problem. And you usually _don't_ get an automatic null-termination, but _some_ string library methods _will_ add a null for you. You need to be always careful about this point.

Comment: @JRaymond, About the first comment, an array is not a pointer. If it was, [this example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/8ae0ed543647bbdc80a0b78caeae1dc6) would print the same size for both.

Comment: @Mackey18 also note that using `realloc` you can grow the size of buffer that's been allocated using `malloc`, so when you choose your buffer sizes, they don't need to be once-and-for-all. e.g. if you're reading a file or a network stream, you can choose an upper-bound, and grow it later as necessary.

Comment: Yes I've come across malloc before, but not realloc. Is malloc used in Objective-C at all?

Answer (score 3):

> How can the author be using chars to store whole strings?

he can't. [You notice the asterisk, right?](http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=280)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `*` is the key. Thanks again, marked you up.

Answer (score 3):

The point your missing is the `*`.

```
char letter = 'a';  //stores a single character
char *word = "bigger"; //stores a string literal
```

this means word is really:

```
word ---> [b][i][g][g][e][r][\0]
```

pointing to a bunch of chars (or a "string" of chars). In your example the author defined:

```
const char *words[4] = { "aardvark", "abacus",      "allude", "zygote" };
```

So you have 4 strings of chars, which are constant. The const was the author's choice to add that on there... it could have been left off. It's just a safeguard, a note to the compiler (and author) that these values were not ment to be modified.

Comment: Thank you Mike for the really clear answer, this has helped me a lot. Marked you up.

Comment: @Mackey18 - Happy to help, we all have to start somewhere :)